# How fast can an artificial human be grown without killing its host?

Tags: biology, magic

Demons need to possess human bodies in order to exist on the mortal plane. However, a human body is fragile, and unable to contain the demonic essence for long. This leads to these bodies breaking down after a short period of time, killing the host and sending the demon back to the nether-realm. What is needed to avoid this is a specially prepared body that is built to hold a demonic essence. These are called homunculi, artificial organisms built in the shape and appearance of a human, but designed specifically to contain a demon permanently.

Homunculi are created through a process called preformationism. Within each of our sex cells contains an animanalcule, or preformed human. Development in the womb is therefore the process of enlarging the human until it is large enough to be born. Homunculi are born to dark witches through this alchemical process in the same way as regular humans. These beings are created through the use of dark rituals and magical potions, and made to gestate inside a living human. Homunculi take the form of a large lump of flesh, similar to a large tumor or a group of cancer-like cells, that would grow to the same size as a 9 month fetus. After it is born, the unformed substance is placed in powder of ground sun stone, sulfur, magnet, and green tutia, which will cause the amorphous blob to grow a human skin.

This abnormal being lacks a soul from God due to the unnatural creation of its birth. This makes it the perfect vessel for a demon, who can bond with this empty vessel permanently. Unfortunately, it takes a much shorter time to incubate, which is a total of forty days. Of course, this is very dangerous for the mother, who would experience all the symptoms of a real pregnancy at a rapid rate of growth. The dark witch obviously would want to survive the process. What is needed is a specialized potion that would need to be taken periodically throughout the process. What must this potion do in order to provide for a safe delivery?

Comment: None of the body text appears to have anything to do with the question at the top. Do you want a biological answer, magical-with-some-constraints, or what?

Comment: Are you basically asking, *how fast can a non-fetus grow in a woman's uterus*? Because very fast.  And if you're using immune suppressants then her body's immune system won't attack it.  This could be a day, week, month, year.  I don't really see a limitation here....

Comment: Seeing as how the lump of flesh doesn't need nutrition from the mother... this bad boy could grow as fast as it wants as long as the mother's immune system doesn't absolutely tear it to shreds, which is helpfully fixed by @cegfault 's suggestion of immune suppressants being created by the Homunculi fetus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A human gestation can be as short as 22 weeks and still yield a viable fetus. The main difficulties are the immaturity of pulmonary and cardiac systems (and, of course, infections), and all three can be remediated by medicine.

So, a little magic would surely allow a human fetus to be born at 22 weeks. It's no great stretch of the imagination to bring it down to 16 weeks if we simplify the "lump of tissue" and factor in the reduced need for sustenance from the mother - no real placenta, no umbilical cord, just absorbing nutrients from the amnion and the attachment structure.

(Gathering energy from black magic instead of chemical processes, the fetus could even absorb extra sustenance from the mother by scrubbing carbon dioxide from the blood, using it not unlike plants and lichens do, to build hydrocarbon and carbohydrate scaffolding; this would have the interesting side effect of inducing [hypocapnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocapnia) in the host).

Birth would be very easy and potentially labor and pain free due to the small size of the fetus and lack of placental expulsion, but you might easily make it so this prevents any future normal pregnancies (either from damage to the womb or immune response - this [even happens in humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolytic_disease_of_the_newborn_(ABO))).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to begot a human with a demon soul instead of one provided by God? This is easily done if a witch have sex in a satanic ritual with some dark priest serving as the father. Or perhaps, go into genetic engineering and artificial insemination to assure that a superhuman flesh will begot.

However, it have a lot of risks. If the satanic ritual is not carried out correctly and thoroughly, there is the risk that the child get a godly soul instead of a satanic one. This is also possible if either the mother or the father still bears a spark of good-being or love deeply hidden in their hearts. Also, even if a fetus with a satanic soul is begotten successfully, the probability of abortion in pregnancy is very high because God really dislikes that.

<sub><sup>Note: Worldbuiling is hilarious for being the only place where I can pretend to be a very evil person. Of course that in reality I don't agree nor believe with any of this.</sup></sub>

Comment: I just imagined the Fallout popup [God really disliked that]